# Why is $\Psi (x,0) = A$ in this problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

[image]

I don't understand the answer to part a. The solution set says that $\Psi (x,0) = A$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2}$ and $\Psi (x,0) = 0$ otherwise, but I just don't see why. I'm still new to quantum mechanics, so could someone explain this to me? I know it's probably really simple...

Comment: There is no why given in the problem. It is good that you picked up on that, read the question "Suppose we know after many experiments that electrons prepared in some way are equally likely to be found anywhere on the left half of the well at time 0. Write the wave function, $\psi(x,0)$, that matches this observation. "

Comment: You're told that at time $t = 0$, the particle is equally likely to be found anywhere in the left half of the well. So, that just means that the probability density function is constant for $0 < x < a/2$ and is zero outside this region. The probability density function at $t = 0$ is $|\psi(x,0)|^2$, which is of course always real. So, you can infer that $\psi(x,0)$ is some constant for the left half of the well (given to be real), and zero outside. Use normalization to compute this constant.

Comment: The solution for the wave function for a particle in a one dimensional potential well is $\psi_n(x)=A sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)$. The initial condition is that the particle is at $x=\frac{a}{2}$.

Comment: With this in mind, put the initial condition in the expression for the above wave function and see what it does for the constraint $0<x<\frac{a}{2}$